# Why did the Meks in Vance's 'Last Castle' not revolt from the inside?

Tags: plot-device, jack-vance

In the novella *The Last Castle* by Vance, the Meks leave the human castles and proceed to revolt against their former masters from the outside and siege the castles. The revolt proved difficult to win and resulted in many Mek deaths. Why did they not remain in the castles and revolt partly from the inside? That way, it would have been very easy for them to defeat the humans.

Comment: A very quick scan through the book suggests that a number of Meks did revolt within the castles but faced with superior weaponry, the majority escaped and formed raiding parties with the aim of assaulting one city after another.

Comment: @Valorum: Hmm but I seem to remember that the Meks at left Hagedorn prior to the revolt? Now another memory comes up: didn't the humans cut off the Meks' telepathic antennae in the castles, so that the Meks needed to regrow them first before being able to take part in the revolt—or am I confusing this novel with a different story?